# firebase first steps, error installing visualstudio2017tools by node.js installer; DeprecationWarning: Buffer()

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

Node.js installer offered itselfe to install additional tools, among them visualstudio2017-workload-vctools. This installation at some point threw a warning of this matteer:

`(node:7292) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`

Installation was running in the powershell and paused with this warning, not letting me type anything. After some time it fed me with this message:

```
 specified (or the default value) was '2700' seconds. Perhaps try a
 higher `--execution-timeout`? See `choco -h` for details.
  visualstudio2017-workload-vctools may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
The upgrade of visualstudio2017-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey upgraded 16/17 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Upgraded:
(some stuff here)

Failures
 - visualstudio2017-workload-vctools (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2017-workload-vctools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
Type ENTER to exit:
```

I moved on and installed firebase tools via VSCode command line and this one gone as follows:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\eters\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase -> C:\Users\eters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js

> protobufjs@6.10.1 postinstall C:\Users\eters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):nts):                                                                                                                                {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ firebase-tools@8.6.0
added 530 packages from 353 contributors in 962.032s
```

Questions are:

- Can i repair first installation vs2017tools?
- Could I react anyhow when instalation was waiting for 2700 s?
- Will all this influence my firebase experience?
- I do have VS2019 installed can i force nodejs to use this installation?

Thx